# 2GP managed package creation issue

Tags: managed-package

I am trying to create a 2GP managed package. I come across lots of issues and resolved it one by one.
Finally I am struck in this Error

```
=== Package Version Create Request
NAME                           VALUE
─────────────────────────────  ──────────────────
ID                             08c2w0000004DDkAAM
Status                         Error
Package Id                     0Ho2w0000004ClsCAE
Package Version Id
Subscriber Package Version Id
Tag
Branch
Created Date                   2021-01-30 12:03
Installation URL
=== Errors
(1) These entities are not supported: [Group, ProcessDefinition]
```

I read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/51) that "Group" can't be included in Managed Package. but I am using the Group's in to configure Email template. So I cant remove group .

Can some one please help.?

### **Adding Package.xml code**

```
<types>
          <members>unfiled$public/ApprovalEmail</members>
          <members>unfiled$public/SupervisorApproval</members>
          <members>unfiled$public/SupervisorToCaseworker</members>
          <members>unfiled$public/Supervisor_Return</members>
          <members>unfiled$public/CaseworkerToSupervisorContract</members>
          <members>unfiled$public/SupervisorApprovalContract</members>
          <members>unfiled$public/SupervisorApprovalInactiveContract</members>
          <members>unfiled$public/CaseworkerToSupervisor</members>
          <members>unfiled$public/SupervisorApprovalMonitoring</members>
          <members>unfiled$public/SupervisorRejectedMonitoring</members>
         <members>unfiled$public/Training_Assignment</members> 
         <members>unfiled$public/SupervisorApprovalReconsideration</members>        
         <members>unfiled$public/StaffSubmission</members>  
          <name>EmailTemplate</name>
   </types>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any mention of sharing from the email template, as it doesn't make sense in the context of a package. This would need to be a post-install configuration step for an administrator.

Comment: After removing Groups I can able to create package successfully. After that I am trying to install the package in one new scratch org but I am getting this error  " ERROR running force:package:install:  Installation errors:
1) Cannot use unfiled-public or user folders in a package, Details: package.xml: Cannot use unfiled-public or user folders in a package

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner These are report errors. Make sure your reports are in a specially created folder that is included in the package.

Comment: I dont have any reports folder Instead Using email template in unfiled-public folder. I edited my question above and added the Package.xml code

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner Ah, you can't put emails in unfiled public or private folders; it needs to be in an email folder that's in the package.

Comment: Thanks. It helps